# How to add page flip animation to a given HTML content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to render a given HTML file in a book layout, with two columns and page flip animation. The way I have implemented so far is to have horizontal scrolling with 2 columns and to turn page I scroll by screen width, it looks something like this:

[image]

I want to add page flip animation when turning pages, and I have explored some libraries like [StPageFlip](https://github.com/Nodlik/StPageFlip), [turnjs](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js), but all of them require content to be explicitly defined in page like, and if the content doesn't find the page it's truncated -

```
<div id="magazine">
    <div><span class="text">Page 1</span></div>
    <div><span class="text">Page 2</span></div>
    <div><span class="text">Page 3</span></div>
</div>
```

To use them, I'll have to divide the content into smaller divs, make sure the div's content fit the screen size, etc which feels like lot of overhead processing. And how to divide the content such that it always fits the screen?

Is there any library which converts existing html content into book style without having to explicitly define the pages? Or how can I implement a basic version of page flip animation myself, how should I approach it?

Can I somehow add some animation to the current scroll code I have to make it somewhat look like page flip?

```
$(div).animate({
    scrollLeft: scrollLeftValue
},
{
    duration: 300
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your actual HTML structure ? Maybe solution like this one could be adapted : https://codepen.io/timohausmann/pen/xdKkA

Comment: I also saw this codepen, but am not sure how to span contents across multiple pages. If the screen size is not enough the page contents are truncated.

Comment: "*Or how can I implement a basic version of page flip animation myself, how should I approach it?"* - seems like you already have the answer - *" I'll have to divide the content into smaller divs, make sure the div's content fit the screen size, etc"*.

Comment: Are you looking for someone to write this code as open source and give it to you? Sorry I'm a bit confused, there is a lot in this question including asking for library suggestions which is off topic fo the site. I'd suggest asking one specific question that is blocking you from moving forward. Please read [ask]